# Should the output of Apriori algorithm be a one to one relationship

Tags: python, apriori

I am currently following this guide:

https://stackabuse.com/association-rule-mining-via-apriori-algorithm-in-python/

as an output all of the rules are of the form:

```
light cream ----> chicken
```

is this correct, should the output always be a one to one relationship in the apriori algorithm, or can we (or should) we have something like

```
{light cream, chocolate} -----> strawberries
```

Comment: Association rules, and specifically those output by the Apriori algorithm, can definitely be many-to-one.